# Can we interchange the limit and the integration $\lim_{z \to \omega} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-zt}-e^{-\omega t}}{z-\omega} f(t) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose that $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\Re (z),\Re(\omega)>0$. Can we interchange the limit and integration in 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{z \to \omega} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-zt}-e^{-\omega t}}{z-\omega} f(t) dt?
\end{equation*} I feel that I should apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I fail to formulate the integrand in a useful form. Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is not clear at all. You can simply pull $\frac {e^{-z}-e^{-w}} {z-w}$ outside the integral because this factor does not involve $t$. Also you need $f \in L^{1}$ for the integral to exist.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, I really missed the variable $t$ in the quotient, so I have added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We claim that if $|u|\le \delta, t \ge 0, |\frac{e^{ut}-1}{u}| \le te^{\delta t}$. Since $\frac{e^{ut}-1}{u}$ is holomorphic on $|u|\le \delta$, by maximum modulus it is enough to prove the inequality when $|u|=\delta$ and then since $\frac{e^{ut}-1}{u}$ has positive real coefficients, it is enough to prove it for $u=\delta$ which follows immediately from the mean value theorem on the interval $[0,\delta]$

If we let $\Re \omega > 2\delta >0$ and we let $z$ in the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $\omega$, we have $\frac{e^{-zt}-e^{-\omega t}}{z-\omega}=-e^{-\omega t}\frac{e^{ut}-1}{u}, |u| \le \delta $ so by the above $|\frac{e^{-zt}-e^{-\omega t}}{z-\omega}|\le te^{-(\Re \omega-\delta)t} \le te^{-\delta t}=g(t)$

But $f(t)g(t) \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ by Cauchy so $\frac{e^{-zt}-e^{-\omega t}}{z-\omega}f(t)$ is dominated by a fixed integrable function (in $t$) for all $z$ in the given neighborhood of $w$ hence we can switch limits and integrals by the dominated convergence theorem